# How to achieve higher level partitioning in database architecture?

Tags: database, database-design

Lets say I have tables A, B  and C. 
For one scenario D, I can structure my data among these tables.

What if I have multiple instances of Scenario D (D1, D2) and all of those instances are mutually exclusive.

I need a structure like D1->A, D2->A, D1->B, D2->B, D1->C, D2->C. How can achieve this in database architecture.

I don't want to filter all A entries matching D1 to get D1->A, it doesn't seem optimal. I need to be able to access D1->A directly without any overhead.

Answer (score 0):

Filtering all `A` entries matching `D1` to get `D1->A` is usual for SQL-based engines. If you want more efficiency, use proper indexes - then you go through a tree structure to find appropriate `A` set in several jumps and you are good.

But if you want to avoid the overhead completely, you can go with a NoSQL engine. Then you'll have your `D1->A` stored as one document. The only problem here is that you have to maintain such collections by yourself.